# All (*of) the students/contracts

Tags: prepositions, american-english, style-manuals, all-of

According to the [Random House Unabridged Dictionary of American English](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/all)

> Although some object to the inclusion of *of* in such phrases as *all of the students* and *all of the contracts* and prefer to omit it, the construction is entirely standard.

What are the reasons behind such objection? There must be some grammar involved: first the definite article *the*, and second both *students/contracts* are plural and countable.

**** EDIT ****

OED reads (here's the [index](https://mega.nz/file/MhFmnIqS#XIo7arhrDzRIQvEkwRm0oH0zVfJX5Obulx-HlfqVv0k) for the website; if somebody needs to use the cdrom, PM me)

[**OF**](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00162372): XII. Indicating a quality or other distinguishing mark by which a person or thing is characterized. (For OE. genitive; F. de; = genitive of quality or description.)

b. qualified by all, indicating (temporary) condition:

- 1849 Thackeray Pendennis xvi, *‘Do you say so?’ Smirke said, all of a
  tremble*

[**ALL**](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00005828): A. adj. II. absol.

6. Followed by *of*: in sing. The entire amount, every part, the whole; in pl. Every individual, all the members or examples. (This const. is comparatively modern, and is probably due to form-assoc. with *none of, some of, little of, much of, few of, many of*.) Rare, exc. with pronouns, as a*ll of it, of whom, of which, of them*. Also, as much as, altogether, quite; *for all of* (cf. for prep. 26b) U.S., as far as concerns (a person or thing).
   [See pronominal examples under 2c.]

Comment: Probable duplicate of countless related questions, including:
[①](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4863)
[②](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4906)
[③](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/15183)
[④](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/58375)
[⑤](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/65650)
[⑥](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/80412)
[⑦](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/80696)
[⑧](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/92701)
[⑨](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/229266)
[....]

Comment: [...] as well as of:
[⑩](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/288301)
[⑪](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/253617)
[⑫](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/372176)
[⑬](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480196)
and many, many more besides.

Comment: You leave it to the reader to find the '[though it is] entirely standard'. Acceptability (never mind preferred usage) is in the mind of the speaker. Though there is thankfully a lot of agreement, some usages (see Quirk & Greenbaum's study of 'acceptability') are controversial, dividing opinion of usage panels. Bottom line: 'all [the]' and 'all of [the]' are interchangeable in this quantifier usage. _All the king's horses and all of the king's men._

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["All our X" vs. "all of our X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65650/all-our-x-vs-all-of-our-x) I dpn't think even the most ardent pedant would take issue with [*You took the part \ That once was my heart \ So why not take all **of** me.*](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/22776125/Billie+Holiday/All+Of+Me+%28Why+Not+Take%29) That one simply doesn't work at all without ***of***.

Comment: @tchrist that's easy to do; now, answer succintly the (grammatical) "reasons behind such objection"

Comment: @GJC There are no grammatical objections, merely those of style.

Comment: Grammar in the final analysis is crystallised style.

Comment: @GJC I updated the quotation used in your answer. By editing it as you had, you were misrepresenting what it said. If you insist on quoting only a portion of it, use ellipses to indicate that what you provide is not the verbatim source material.

Comment: I've added OED info. Secondly, there must be some grammar involve: first the definite article _the_, and second both _students/contracts_ are plural and countable

Comment: This question ISN'T a duplicate

Comment: **all of**  "Not more than": _a conversation that took all of five minutes_

Answer (score 2):

There are people with far too high an opinion of their knowledge who criticize what they don't understand. That's the real explanation.

*Of* is a preposition; probably the most common one in English.
It's got  thousands of special uses with special idioms

> (Describe the meaning of *of* in the phrase *the apple of my eye*, for instance)

and having duties in possessive constructions with inanimate nouns (*the arm of the chair*),
and marking verbal arguments during nominalizations (*the shooting of the hunters*).

It's also a monosyllable /əv/ and it gets shortened often, since it's not stressed. Since there are only two phonemes in it, shortening can result either in a vowel /ə/ or a consonant /v/. Interestingly, these are also what the auxiliary verb *have* shortens into when **it** is unstressed, which is normally the case for auxiliary *have* of the perfect

- *He would have gone.* /hi'wʊdəv'ɡɔn/

leading to the classic misspelling (with identical pronunciation)

- *He would of gone.*

This is one place where people who pay too  much attention to "correct" grammar get mistrustful of *of*. Of course it's silly, because people can't misspell what they're saying, but it's one way to put people down, and for too many people grammar is only good for putting people down.

Another way is to say that *of* is "unnecessary". This generally means that whoever has made the judgement does not understand what the function of the word is, and, noting that it can often be deleted, decides that it must always be deleted. And says so, and says that that is The Rule.

A good example is the phrase *off of*, normally pronounced /'ɔfə/, as in

- *He had trouble keeping the cat off of the chair.*

which can also be said without *of*:

- *He had trouble keeping the cat off the chair.*

The fact is that sometimes one wants an extra syllable and sometimes one doesn't,
and this optional *of* provides it when one needs it.

With quantifiers like *all, each, any, some, many, much, few,* etc. there are a lot of patterns,

- some with *of* required (*all of us*, but **all us*),
- some with *of* optional (*all the men, all of the men*),
- some with *of* but a different number (*each man, each of the men*)
- and some without *of* (*few houses,* but **few of houses*).

There are also interactions with articles and other prepositions. So it gets very complicated and there are lots of conflicting rules and that's when people get confused and start paying attention to opinions instead of facts. Since Anglophone schools no longer teach English grammar, and ESL classes always use their own teachers' versions of it, there is a great deal of confusion and attendant objection to almost everything about English grammar. Just consider the questions, comments, and answers on this site for examples.

Comment: I've added OED info to OP. Secondly, there must be some grammar involving both the definite article the, and second  plural and countable nouns.

Comment: **all of**  "Not more than": _a conversation that took all of five minutes_

Comment: "Some"? There are hundreds of rules about article use, and hundreds more about _of_. And those are just the real rules, the ones that speakers follow. There are thousands of zombie rules that aren't true. English grammatical rules are much more likely to license some construction than to forbid it.